# Custom field in root of JSON result in Django Rest Framework ListApiView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The result of ListApiView In django rest framework is something like this:

```
{
"count": 1023
"next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
"previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
"results": [
   …
]
}
```

how can I add a custom field in root of JSON result and not in the results list like this?

```
{
"my_custom_field": ...
"count": 1023
"next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
"previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
"results": [
   …
]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify your `pagination_class`. Create a new pagination class and override the `get_paginated_response` method as you like.

```
class Pagination(PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'my_custom_field': ....,
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })

class SomeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = Pagination
    ...
```

In `Pagination` class, observe `get_paginated_response` You can have your own field there.

Comment: is there another way for when Pagination is not used?

Comment: Basically, this type of response is only possible when you have pagination settings in your code. So to modify it, this is the easiest way.